# Python 3.6: Histogram based on a column with a space in its name

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to make a histogram plot, which normally is no problem, but the column I want to make histogram out of has a space in its name.

Column name: 'Type 1'

Attempt:

```
a = datapok['Type 1'].value_counts(dropna =False)
a.Type 1.plot(kind = 'hist',bins = 50,figsize = (15,15))
```

which I knew wouldn't work.
result:

```
File "<ipython-input-25-b861d1bdb038>", line 2
a.Type 1.plot(kind = 'hist',bins = 50,figsize = (15,15))
^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried creating a variable with the string 'Type 1' and use the variable in place of 'Type 1' but that is also invalid.

Anyone have any ideas on the correct approach of making a histogram based off a column with a space in its name?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `datapok` is a pandas.DataFrame. If so, then `a` is already based on the `Type 1` column, as in it is a Series object. You just need to do:

```
fig = a.plot(kind = 'hist',bins = 50,figsize = (15,15))
fig.figure #shows the figure
```

Comment: I tried the method you suggested: 'a = datapok['Type 1'].value_counts(dropna =False)
a.plot(kind = 'hist',bins = 50,figsize = (15,15))
a.figure #shows the figure' but it also causes an error. Probably because datapok has multiple columns. Sorry for not making that clearer in my original post. If it helps Type 1 is the fourth column.

Comment: @BrightHalo What is the error? `a` is already just one column since you assigned it using `datapok['Type 1']`, which is slicing the dataframe using column name.

Comment: Error: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-0c3848fe3a4f> in <module>()
      2 #a.Type 1.plot(kind = 'hist',bins = 50,figsize = (15,15))
      3 a.plot(kind = 'hist',bins = 50,figsize = (15,15))
----> 4 a.figure #shows the figure

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   3612             if name in self._info_axis:
   3613                 return self[name]`

Comment: `-> 3614             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   3615 
   3616     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'figure'`

Comment: I removed the `#a.Type 1.plot(kind = 'hist',bins = 50,figsize = (15,15))` comment and then the error is: `AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-dfce176771d2> in <module>()
      2 
      3 a.plot(kind = 'hist',bins = 50,figsize = (15,15))
----> 4 a.figure #shows the figure

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   3612             if name in self._info_axis:
   3613                 return self[name]
-> 3614             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)`

Comment: `3615 
   3616     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'figure'`

Comment: @BrightHalo Oh Im sorry. I forgot to assign the plot to a variable name. Please try with the above code.